# Why does xrandr shows refresh rates as floats instead of integers?

Tags: xrandr

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.01 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00*
   ...
```

It's not a problem, just curiosity: why are there options that are not integers?

Comment: Why do you think those are floats?  Maybe they are fixed point?  And why should refresh rates be multiples of 1, rather than say, multiples of 0.01?

Comment: The reason doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu or even xrandr. These are real refresh rates. Look up PAL and NTSC or research the history of television resolutions and refresh rates. It's a curious topic, but I'm VTC this question as off-topic just as it would be off topic to ask why monitors use 1080 vertical lines instead of 1000.